# Display Google Places photos in android device

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, google-places-api

Hi I'm working on Google Places API, with Google Places Photo request I can get different images of a specific place. But I don't know how to display this image in a android device.

This is the request URL that I'm using to retrieve the image
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CoQBegAAAFg5U0y-iQEtUVMfqw4KpXYe60QwJC-wl59NZlcaxSQZNgAhGrjmUKD2NkXatfQF1QRap-PQCx3kMfsKQCcxtkZqQ&sensor=true&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

Need some help on this..

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper

include the library in your project.
and use the following code

UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(imageView, "YOUR URL HERE");

its very simple